# Intercept HTTP Request in page

Tags: ruby, http, web-scraping, python-requests, token

I am trying to make a **scraper** for a page of a supermarket. I noticed that this supermarket make API HTTP calls via AJAX, and if I enter to Inspect > Network then I can see the request headers of the calls I need.

Inside the requests headers there is an X-Token. If I use this X-Token with the URL via Postman I can get all the info in JSON format, which is better than **scraping** the web.

The problem is that this X-Token expires (I think, it still works). Is there any possibility to make a call to the page and "intercept" this API call in order to retrieve this X-Token and use it for the next custom requests?

I'am using Ruby on Rails :)

Comment: You should analyse the JS of the supermarket's page to understand where this X-Token in the AJAX request comes from.

Comment: Uh, yeap. But the JS is hidden and kind of unreadable :(

Comment: Then maybe you should use a headless browser to make it easier.

Comment: You should probally check the Terms of Service of said API before proceeding. If the information is not publically available and requires authentication its not considered fair game. https://medium.com/@tjwaterman99/web-scraping-is-now-legal-6bf0e5730a78

Comment: Ouh! didn't know that. Thank you!

Comment: FYI it's __scraper__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scrape__) not scrapper